# Derivative of a multivariate function w.r.t. a multivariate function

Tags: calculus

Given \begin{equation} f(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left[\varphi(H(X))I_{\{H(X) \geq \gamma\}}\right] \end{equation} where $\theta = (\mu, \Sigma)$, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[\cdot]$ is the expectation w.r.t. the Gaussian distribution $f(\theta, x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{k}\vert \Sigma \vert}}\exp{(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu))}$. Also $H(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ a scalar and $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.

What is the derivate of $f$ w.r.t $(v_1, v_2)$ where $v_1 = \Sigma^{-1}\mu$ and $v_2 = \frac{-1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}$.